# Mailcow - postfix slow sending

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, email-server

I have mailcow with postfix installed on hetzner cloud. I am not system administrator, just developer but I setuped somehow mail server and it seems working. Problem is ,that I dont understand, is that email is sending slow, about 10 seconds. For enduser this is bad experience so I am trying to resolve this. In logs I found this delay

```
postfix-mailcow_1    | Aug 21 10:21:03 mail postfix/smtps/smtpd[609]: warning: hostname mail......club does not resolve to address 2a01:...::1: Temporary failure in name resolution
postfix-mailcow_1    | Aug 21 10:21:03 mail postfix/smtps/smtpd[609]: connect from unknown[2a01:......:ae58::1]
postfix-mailcow_1    | Aug 21 10:21:03 mail postfix/smtps/smtpd[609]: TLS SNI mail......com from unknown[2a01:.....::1] not matched, using default chain
postfix-mailcow_1    | Aug 21 10:21:03 mail postfix/smtps/smtpd[609]: Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[2a01:.....8::1]: TLSv1.3 with cipher TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (256/256 bits) key-exchange X25519 server-signature RSA-PSS (2048 bits) server-digest SHA256
postfix-mailcow_1    | Aug 21 10:21:03 mail postfix/smtps/smtpd[609]: 5F7741C3E28: client=unknown[2a01:.....::1], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=support@.....com
postfix-mailcow_1    | Aug 21 10:21:03 mail postfix/cleanup[614]: 5F7741C3E28: message-id=a5b86d0e4f82708f3e5b8bfa6c5e3d60@www.......com
postfix-mailcow_1    | Aug 21 10:21:11 mail postfix/qmgr[342]: 5F7741C3E28: from=support@......com, size=7756, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
postfix-mailcow_1    | Aug 21 10:21:11 mail postfix/smtps/smtpd[609]: disconnect from unknown[2a01.....::1] ehlo=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=6
postfix-mailcow_1    | Aug 21 10:21:11 mail postfix/smtp[615]: 5F7741C3E28: replace: header Received: from www........com (unknown [IPv6:.....:ae: Received: from [127.0.0.1] (localhost [127.0.0.1]) by localhost (Mailerdaemon) with ESMTPSA id 5F7741C3E28??for etet@yopmail.com; Fri, 21 Aug 2020 10:21:03 +0200 (CEST)
postfix-mailcow_1    | Aug 21 10:21:11 mail postfix/smtp[615]: 5F7741C3E28: to=etet@yopmail.com, relay=smtp.yopmail.com[87.....155]:25, delay=8.5, delays=8.2/0.04/0.16/0.09, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 mail saved)
postfix-mailcow_1    | Aug 21 10:21:11 mail postfix/qmgr[342]: 5F7741C3E28: removed
```

so from 03 seconds to 11 seconds some waiting or I dont know what. Can someone please suggest what can I do?

Comment: Check mail queue and make sure there's no spam/flooding going on.

Comment: no, it's empty, this is fresh server/domain without any load

Comment: Maybe a DNS issue ? Are you sure that the name of the server is correctely resolved (or set in /etc/hosts).

Comment: It takes 8 seconds for user to upload the mail. This suggests the problem is with the user's computer or network connection. Not your server.

Comment: Ah I see now, so this times take to php/apache2 to connect and upload email to smtp server? Something like that? I am using connection string like
smtp://mail.host.com:587?encryption=tls&auth_mode=login&username=support@host.com&password=11111